# My program is assigning a value to ALL objects in an array. What's happening and how do I prevent it ? (VB 2008)

Tags: vb.net

I have exhausted all of my options and am very desperate for help since I cannot figure out where the bug in my code is, or if there is something I don't understand.

I'm trying to create a "methinks it is a weasel!" mimmick from Richard Dawkins' late 80s documentary about evolution.  The goal is to progress through a genetic algorithm until the algorithm guesses the correct answer through mutation and fitness tournaments.

Now, here's the problem:

```
    Private Function fitnessTourney(ByVal editGuess() As Guess, ByVal popIndex As Integer, ByVal tourneySize As Integer, ByVal popNum As Integer)
    Dim randInt(tourneySize - 1) As Integer
    Dim loopCount1 As Integer = 0
    Dim fitnessWinner As New Guess
    fitnessWinner.setFitness(-50)
```

...
And, this loop is where I am experiencing the critical error
...

```
    For i = 0 To tourneySize - 1
        Randomize()
        randInt(i) = Int(Rnd() * popNum)
        While editGuess(randInt(i)).Used = True
            If loopCount1 > tourneySize Then
                loopCount1 = 0
                For i2 = 0 To popNum - 1
                    editGuess(i2).setUsed(False)
                Next
                i = -1
                Continue For
            End If
            loopCount1 += 1
            randInt(i) = Int(Rnd() * popNum)
        End While
        editGuess(randInt(i)).determineFitness(correctPhrase)
        editGuess(randInt(i)).setUsed(True)
    Next
    For i = 0 To popNum - 1
        editGuess(i).setUsed(False)
    Next
```

What this loop is trying to do is pick out four random instances of the editGuess array of objects.  This loop tries to prevent one from being used multiple times, as the population is competing to one of the 10 members (highest fitness of the 4 chosen candidates is supposed to win).

The critical error  is that I mysteriously get an endless loop where any instances of editGuess(randInt(i)).Used will always evaluate to true.  I have tried to fix this by resetting all instances to False if it loops too many times.

The stumper is that I'll have all instances evaluate to False in the debugger.  Then, when I reach "editGuess(randInt(i)).setUsed(True)" (the exact same thing as "editGuess(randInt(i)).Used = True"), it sets this value for EVERY member of the array.

Is there anyone who can see what is happening?  I am so close to completing this!

Here's the Guess class:

```
    Public Class Guess
Dim Fitness As Integer
Dim strLength As Integer
Dim strArray(30) As String
Dim guessStr As String
Dim Used As Boolean
Public Sub New()
    Fitness = 0
    guessStr = ""
    strLength = 0
    Used = 0
End Sub
Public Sub determineFitness(ByVal correctPhrase As String)
    Dim lowerVal
    If guessStr.Length <= correctPhrase.Length Then
        lowerVal = guessStr.Length
    Else
        lowerVal = correctPhrase.Length
    End If
    strArray = guessStr.Split("")
    Fitness = 0 - Math.Abs(correctPhrase.Length - guessStr.Length)
    For i = 0 To lowerVal - 1
        If correctPhrase(i) = guessStr(i) Then
            Fitness = Fitness + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub Mutate(ByVal mutatepercentage As Decimal, ByVal goodLetters As String)
    If mutatepercentage > 100 Then
        mutatepercentage = 100
    End If
    If mutatepercentage < 0 Then
        mutatepercentage = 0
    End If
    mutatepercentage = mutatepercentage / 100
    If Rnd() < mutatepercentage Then
        strLength = Int(Rnd() * 25) + 5
        If strLength < guessStr.Length Then
            guessStr = guessStr.Remove(strLength - 1)
        End If
    End If
    For i = 0 To strLength - 1
        If Rnd() < mutatepercentage Then
            If i < guessStr.Length Then
                guessStr = guessStr.Remove(i, 1).Insert(i, goodLetters(Int(Rnd() * goodLetters.Length)))
            Else
                guessStr = guessStr & goodLetters(Int(Rnd() * goodLetters.Length))
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub setFitness(ByVal num As Integer)
    Fitness = num
End Sub
Public Sub setStrLength(ByVal num As Integer)
    strLength = num
End Sub
Public Sub initializeText()

End Sub
Public Sub setUsed(ByVal bVal As Boolean)
    Used = bVal
End Sub
```

End Class

And, finally, here's where and how the function is called

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    population1(counter) = fitnessTourney(population1, counter, 4, 10)
    population2(counter) = fitnessTourney(population2, counter, 4, 10)
    population1(counter).Mutate(2, goodLetters)
    population2(counter).Mutate(20, goodLetters)
    Label1.Text = population1(counter).guessStr
    Label2.Text = population2(counter).guessStr
    counter += 1
    If counter > 9 Then
        counter = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

EDIT 1:
Thank  you guys for your comments.

Here is the custom constructor I use to the form.  This is used to populate the population arrays that are passed to the fitnessTourney function with editGuess.

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Randomize()
    For i = 0 To 9
        population1(i) = New Guess
        population2(i) = New Guess
    Next
    counter = 0
    correctPhrase = "Methinks it is a weasel!"
    goodLetters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ !@#$%^&*()_+-=?></.,;\|`'~"
    goodLettersArr = goodLetters.Split("")
    For i = 0 To 9
        population1(i).setStrLength(Int(Rnd() * 25) + 5)
        population2(i).setStrLength(Int(Rnd() * 25) + 5)
        For i2 = 0 To population1(i).strLength
            population1(i).guessStr = population1(i).guessStr & goodLetters(Int(Rnd() * goodLetters.Length))
        Next
        For i2 = 0 To population2(i).strLength
            population2(i).guessStr = population2(i).guessStr & goodLetters(Int(Rnd() * goodLetters.Length))
        Next
        Label1.Text = population1(i).guessStr
        Label2.Text = population2(i).guessStr
    Next
    population1(0).guessStr = correctPhrase
    population1(0).determineFitness(correctPhrase)
End Sub
```

Comment: after a quick glance, could you explain what you're doing in your second code block where you set i=-1 then continue for? You are setting i outside the range of the for?

Comment: Can you show the code where you populate the editGuess array.  The behavior you described makes it seem like all the array indices point to the same object, so that when you set one to True, they all get set!

Comment: peterG - The for loop where I set i to -1 was an attempted fix to the problem.  When I had the problem where all members of the array evaluated to true (causing the infinite loop) I had a counter (loopCounter1) put in there.  IF the loop counter was greater than the number of elements I was setting, it would reset all editGuess.Used values to false and restart the loop in hopes that would prevent the problem (I was desperate when I put this in).

Comment: Chris Dunaway -- Code is there.  It is in the constructor to the form.

Comment: OK to clarify, you are saying you single step the code to this line: editGuess(randInt(i)).setUsed(True)
and setused is false for every member, then you single-step that line and then setused is true for every member? Because I don't see how that can be the case; and that implies that somehow you are looking in the wrong place . . .

Answer (score 0):

I haven't studied all of your code thoroughly, but one big problem is that you are calling `Randomize` from within the loop.  Every time you call `Randomize`, it re-seeds the random numbers with the current time.  Therefore, if you call it multiple times before the clock changes, you will keep getting the first "random" number in the sequence using that time which will always evaluate to the same number.  When generating "random" numbers, you want to re-seed your random number generator as few times as possible.  Preferably, you'd only seed it once when the application starts.

As a side note, you shouldn't be using the old VB6 style `Randomize` and `Rnd` methods.  Those are only provided in VB.NET for backwards compatibility.  You should instead be using the `Random` class.  It's easier to use too.  With the `Random` class, you don't even need to call a randomize-like method, since it automatically seeds itself at the point in time when you instantiate the object.  So, in the case of the `Random` class, the thing to be careful is to make sure that you only instantiate the object once before entering any loop where you might be using it.  If you create a new `Random` object inside a loop, it will similarly keep generating the same numbers.